# OpenCV/MSVC C4265 (no virtual destructor) error can not be disabled via command-line

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to use OpenCV in an existing project but I keep getting this error message:

```
d:\downloads\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp(4903) : error C4265: 'cv::TLSDataContainer' : class has virtual functions, but destructor is not virtual
     instances of this class may not be destructed correctly
```

I was trying to disable the error message by passing `/wd4265` but it didn't help! For reference, below is the full command-line.

```
[1/2] cl /nologo /c /W4 /WX- /MP /Gm- /Gs /Gy- /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t- /Gd /TP ...on\cinema 4d r17 dev\plugins\stage\build\nr.hantmade_addons\obj\source\main.obj" FAILED: cl /nologo /c /W4 /WX- /MP /Gm- /Gs /Gy- /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t- /Gd /TP /wd4062 /wd4100 /wd4127 /wd4131 /wd4201 /wd4210 /wd4242 /wd4244 /wd4245 /wd4305 /wd4310 /wd4324 /wd4355 /wd4365 /wd4389 /wd4505 /wd4512 /wd4611 /wd4706 /wd4718 /wd4740 /wd4748 /wd4996 /FC /errorReport:prompt /vmg /vms /w44263 /we4264 /FS /showIncludes /MT /Ox /Oy- /Oi /Ob2 /Ot /GF /DWIN32 /D__PC /DMAXON_API /DMAXON_TARGET_WINDOWS /DMAXON_TARGET_RELEASE /DMAXON_TARGET_64BIT /D__LEGACY_API "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\plugins\stage\source" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\plugins\stage\stage\res" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\plugins\stage\stage\res\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\plugins\stage\vendor\hantmade-license\include" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\python\Python.win64.framework\include" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\plugins\stage\vendor\maxon.c4d\fix\python_api" /Id:\downloads\opencv\build\include "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source\c4d_customgui" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source\c4d_gv" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source\c4d_libs" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source\c4d_misc" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source\c4d_misc\datastructures" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source\c4d_misc\memory" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source\c4d_misc\utilities" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source\c4d_preview" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\frameworks\cinema.framework\source\c4d_scaling" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\res\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\advanced render\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\alembic\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\archigrass\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\browser\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\c4dplugin\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\ca\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\ca2\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\cineman\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\clothilde\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\collada14\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\collada15\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\compositing\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\dwg\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\dwgobjects\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\dynamics\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\exchanges\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\expressiontag\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\fbx\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\hair\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\houdiniconfig\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\houdiniengine\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\iges\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\io_obj\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\i_skp\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\licenseserver\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\mocca\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\model\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\mograph\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\motioncam\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\motiontracker\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\newman\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\objects\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\okino\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\python\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\relaxuv\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\sculpt\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\sculptbrushes\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\shader\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\sketch\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\sky\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\sla\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\teamrender\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\thinking particles\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\tpoperators\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\walkthrough\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\xpressocore\description" "/Ic:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\resource\modules\xtensions\description" /FIlegacy.h /wd4265 "c:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\plugins\stage\source\main.cpp" /Fo"c:\maxon\cinema 4d r17 dev\plugins\stage\build\nr.hantmade_addons\obj\source\main.obj"
```

It works when I add `#pragma warning(disable:4265)` before including OpenCV! I have absolutely no clue where this is coming from. I'd absolutely prefer to disable this warning in the compile script instead of in the code.

Using MSVC 18.00.40418 x64 (vc120) on Windows 10. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found out that the Vendor SDK turns the warning into an error.

```
// ge_sys_math.h
#ifdef MAXON_TARGET_WINDOWS
  #pragma warning(disable:4805) // boolean
  #pragma warning(error: 4265)  // non-virtual destructor of virtual classes

  #define __TYPES_READY
#endif
```

So I guess there is not really another way for me other than to disable the warning in the code.